# how to add a click event to svelte-simple-datatables

Tags: javascript, svelte

how can I add the event to the table, so that it can save the data of the selected row in a variable, when I click on the row?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs, `svelte-simple-datatables` lets you pass in a template for the rows. This means you can add a click event listener to the `tr`. Modified example of the [readme](https://github.com/vincjo/svelte-simple-datatables):

```
<script>
    import { Datatable, rows } from 'svelte-simple-datatables'

    const settings = {
        sortable: true,
        pagination: true,
        rowPerPage: 50,
        columnFilter: true,
    }
    let data = [ {} /* ..your data*/];
    let selectedIndex = -1;
</script>

<Datatable settings={settings} data={data}>
    <thead>
        <!-- header definition .. -->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {#each $rows as row, index}
        <tr on:click={() => selectedIndex = index}>
            <td>{row.id}</td>
            <!-- etc.. -->
        </tr>
    {/each}
    </tbody>
</Datatable>
```

Comment: I guess it's just a matter of taste but I would recommend to define the `selectedIndex`'s default value to `null` instead of `-1`.